# Запрет на получение данных $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как правильно реализовать логику работы формы поиска, чтобы

1.при пустой форме контент блока сохранялся в переменную, а при вводе какой либо строки выполнялся бы .get запрос на страницу `/test?field=somestring`. Полученный контент замещает имеющийся в блоке.

2.При очищении поля необходимо, чтобы возвращался тот самый исходный контент. При очищении поля посылается .get запрос на страницу `/test?field=`, который совсем ни к чему, и его надо заблокировать или как вариант при пустом поле вставлять переменную с изначальным контентом.

```js
function get_query() {
  if ($("#search-text").val() != '') {
    $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", {
        field: $("#search-text").val()
      },
      function(content) {
        $("#res").html(content);
      });
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-button").on("click", get_query);
  $("#search-text").on("keyup", get_query);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-search">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search-text" placeholder="Поиск по чему либо" data-search="" class="form-control" />
  <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-default btn-search">Искать</button>
  <a href="#" class="clear-search" title="Очистить">Очистить</a>
</div>


<div id="res" class="row filtr-container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function get_query() {
    if ($("#search-text").val() != '') {
        $.get("/search", {
                field: $("#search-text").val()
            },
            function (content) {
                $("#res").html(content);
            })
    } else {
        $("#res").load('/ #res');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-button").on("click", get_query);
    $("#search-text").on("keyup", get_query);
});
```

Оставил этот вариант, перехват заключается в пустом поле,при котором мы заново загружаем изначальное поле .res